# Vue Laravel Axios Post not working on Android 7

Tags: android, laravel, vue.js, axios

I have a Vue.js template that has a form. Here is an example of the post:

```
axios.post('/url', $('$form').serialize()).then(response => {...}).catch(error => {...});
// Laravel has a series of if statements that make sql exec calls.
if (request()->input('condition') == 1 && request()->input('condition2') == 1){ 
try {run sql update;} 
catch (Exception $e) {//no worries} 
try { run sql exec;} 
catch (Exception $e) {$error = "log error";}
...}
```

The problem here is it works fine on a PC but on an android 7.0 device running chrome 69.x it is not getting to the sql exec function. Is there something I could be missing, like poor wifi, but even then the other functions that process this route work fine.

Comment: You are missing a `)` after `serialize`, not sure if this is a typo or the actual error

Comment: This is abbreviated example code. There are no errors thrown.